# Unable to locate element, using webdriver on VS 2013 & C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m73N.png)Webdriver is Unable to locate an element

webdriver is failing to locate this element  id="frameworkContainer" on my web page (attached is the image of html). I have used xpath, cssslocator, classname and ID.
I'm using webdriver on VS2013 with C#.. can  someone shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to switch to the iFrame before you're able to find any elements inside it. As there is an ID, the best way will be to find the element by it.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(iFrameLocator);
```